# within group sorts in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, rank, percentile

I have a panel data set: that is, `times`, `ids`, and `values`.  I would like to do a ranking based on value for each date.  I can achieve the sort very simply by running:

```
select * from tbl order by date, value
```

The issue I have is once the table is sorted in this way, how do I retrieve the row number of each group (that is, for each date I would like there to be a column called ranking that goes from 1 to N).

Example:

Input:

```
Date, ID, Value
 d1, id1, 2
 d1, id2, 1
 d2, id1, 10
 d2, id2, 11
```

Output:

```
Date, ID, Value, Rank
 d1, id2, 1, 1
 d1, id1, 2, 2
 d2, id1, 10, 1
 d2, id2, 11, 2
```

Comment: Please don't name columns after SQL reserved words like DATE, even for illustrative purposes.

Comment: no, date is not a reserved word (due to the fact of too many people misuse on it, mysql allow date to be non-reserved)

Comment: @ajreal: Could @pilcrow possibly mean that `DATE` is a *standard* SQL reserved word? I mean, I am not sure if there is such a thing.

Comment: Even if it is not reserved, it's not good practice to use `date` or `time` as table of column names. Too much confusion with the `DATE()` function or the `DATE` datatype.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html -- `MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them. Examples are those in the following list: ...`

Comment: PS: I don't mean to encourage use of date or something very reserved keyword alike, but is just not a problem in mysql at the moment ... don't get upset

Comment: these are all good points.  the column in my database is named "dte" for this purpose. your points are all well taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absent window functions, you can order `tbl` and use user variables to compute rank over your partitions ("date" values) yourself:

```
SELECT "date",                                                -- D) Desired columns
       id,
       value,
       rank
  FROM (SELECT "date",                                        -- C) Rank by date
               id,
               value,
               CASE COALESCE(@partition, "date")
                 WHEN "date" THEN @rank := @rank + 1
                 ELSE             @rank := 1
               END AS rank,
               @partition := "date" AS dummy
          FROM (SELECT @rank := 0 AS rank,                    -- A) User var init
                       @partition := NULL AS partition) dummy
               STRAIGHT_JOIN
               (  SELECT "date",                              -- B) Ordering query
                         id,
                         value
                    FROM tbl
                ORDER BY date, value) tbl_ordered;
```

### Update

So, what is that query doing?

We are using *user variables* to "loop" through a sorted result set, incrementing or resetting a counter (`@rank`) depending upon which contiguous segment of the result set (tracked in `@partition`) we're in.

In query **A** we initialize two user variables.  In query **B** we get the records of your table in the order we need:  first by date and then by value.  **A** and **B** together make a derived table, `tbl_ordered`, that looks something like this:

```
rank | partition | "date" |  id  | value 
---- + --------- + ------ + ---- + -----
  0  |   NULL    |   d1   |  id2 |    1
  0  |   NULL    |   d1   |  id1 |    2
  0  |   NULL    |   d2   |  id1 |   10
  0  |   NULL    |   d2   |  id2 |   11
```

Remember, we don't really care about the columns `dummy.rank` and `dummy.partition` — they're just accidents of how we initialize the variables `@rank` and `@partition`.

In query **C** we loop through the derived table's records.  What we're doing is more-or-less what the following pseudocode does:

```
rank      = 0
partition = nil

foreach row in fetch_rows(sorted_query):
  (date, id, value) = row

  if partition is nil or partition == date:
    rank += 1
  else:
    rank = 1

  partition = date

  stdout.write(date, id, value, rank, partition)
```

Finally, query **D** projects all columns from **C** *except* for the column holding `@partition` (which we named `dummy` and do not need to display).

Comment: thank you for this.  i am trying to follow this query but it is a bit complicated. could you please give a little bit of a commentary on what is going on here?

Comment: thank you for your help. very clear explanation.. perfect for someone without much SQL experience as myself!

Comment: brilliant approach!
rename the partition attr from the dummy table because MySQL will get confused. - "@partition := NULL AS partition"

Comment: Thanks, @ninjabber.  This kind of manual partitioning gets unwieldy quickly — you sorely miss windowing/analytic function when you want to partition on three or more criteria — but it works well enough for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but here is a shorter answer:

```
SELECT w.*, if(
      @preDate = w.date,
      @rank := @rank + 1,
      @rank := (@preDate :=w.date) = w.date
    ) rank
FROM tbl w
JOIN (SELECT @preDate := '' )a
ORDER BY date, value
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the trick?

```
select [DATE],ID,Value, 
(DENSE_RANK()  OVER (   
   PARTITION BY ID
 ORDER BY Date) )AS [DenseRank],    
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS RN     
from SomeTable
```

Comment: You might reserve an answer like this for a question about SQL Server. (Although I must say that you should also pay more attention to the question you are answering: partitioning was supposed to be done by `Date`, not by `ID`, and ordering was more likely by `Value` than by anything else.)